# jasper report export excel without page header

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I created a template using jaspser studio. On the server, I am able to export the report out to excel. However, what I want is have the excel file only contain the column header and data, without the page header, footer, and any other ornaments. I saw a lot of tutorials using java programming. I am wondering whether there is a way to get this without programming in either java or xml.

For clarification, modifying some properties in xml file is ok. I just meant not creating a new xml from scratch.

Comment: Which kind of programming is allowed?, if none I don't know if SO is the right place to ask ; )

Comment: interesting point. actually jasper studio accepts java snippets. It's kind of java programming in a tight container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible through Jaspersoft Studio. More detail is available [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-can-i-suppress-page-headers-and-footers-when-exporting-xls)

You will need to add a new property to the report itself (Right Click > Show Properties > Advanced. Then properties under Misc.).

Then you will need to add the following properties (For XLS format):

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.1" value="pageHeader"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.2" value="pageFooter"/>
```

If you are exporting to a XLSx format you will need to change `xls` to `xlsx` in the property name, like so:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xlsx.exclude.origin.band.1" value="pageHeader"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xlsx.exclude.origin.band.2" value="pageFooter"/>
```

If you need to exclude more bands, there should be suitable information in the link I provided.

Comment: "without programming in either java or xml", you actually changed the xml (the jrxml).... but answer is good and appreciated (it may come in handy for someone else)...., I think he intends without programming changing settings on jasper report server....

Comment: I interpreted the question to be about avoiding the manual typing of jrxml instead of editing it in any form but I see what you are saying. Have rolled back to include the jrxml.

Comment: Yes I agree it can be interpret like this, lets see what OP does, if you are right, lets change his question to make this clear, if you are wrong you can leave the answer anyway (maybe a comment under) since you are not answering only for OP. As answer I feel this is better since if you wan't to do it with IDE its not difficult to understand furthermore it is the actual jrxml code. (you naturally answer as you wish)

Comment: I followed the instructions exactly. added the two properties, but had no effect. The page headers and footer still show up like before.

Comment: If you could update your question to include your jrxml, it would be useful to understand your issue better and find a solution which is suitable

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent displaying columns header through condition expression in **display if** property like the below

```
$P{format}.equals("xlsx") ? new Boolean(false) : new Boolean(true)
```

**format** is a parameter that you can pass when your call report generating is triggered.
you can even prevent displaying this kind of stuffs in other pages except the first one for example :

```
$V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1 ? new Boolean(true) : new Boolean(false)
```